# Inserting copied cells from range to blank cells in another range

Tags: excel, vba, insert, range

*Image depicting data and underlying excel file*

[Ranges example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-_jipWKnxPvV2FrYzdtQ2N1Mjg)

[Underlying excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-_jipWKnxPvc2hDcHYxTjJBcXc)

*Issue and what I have tried*

- I have a table here named range 2, which I wish to insert in the blank areas in the table named range 1, such that in aggregate it looks like range 3.
- I have tried copying the range, then selecting range 1, marking the blank areas using : home -> find&select -> go to special -> select blanks, and then insert copied cells. This fails, and I get the message ''This cant be done on multiple range selection. Select single range and try again''. I have further tried using the record macro tool to try VBA, but did not succeed.

  - Note: I have a much bigger set similar to range 1 with the exact same structure with blank cells that need to be filled, else I wouldve of course done this manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, cel As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- your own sheet name here
        Set r1 = .Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set r2 = .Range("G3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
        Set r3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        For Each cel In r1
            If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
                r3.Resize(1, 4).value = cel.Resize(1, 4).value
                Set r3 = r3.Offset(1)
            Else
                r3.Resize(r2.Rows.Count, r2.Columns.Count).value = r2.value
                Set r3 = r3.Offset(r2.Rows.Count)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about what you are trying to do. Both of which you can do with VBA if you have to do repeatedly

1. place Range 1 and Range 2 on separate sheets
2. Delete all empty rows in Range 1 and Range 2 on their respective sheets
3. Then copy Range 1 then Range 2 to aggregate

(this will not fill voids but it will aggregate them together and you can then filter or pivot table the data easily)

if you want to go about it the complicated way though you will have to

1. loop through your Range 1 data and record all rows which are empty
2. loop through Range 2 data and record how many records there are
3. loop through Range 2 and cut each row and paste through the recorded empty rows from Range 1
4. If there are more rows of data in Range 2, place excess below range 1
5. If there are less rows of data in Range 2, throw an error or delete the additional empty rows in Range 1

(this would require a little more thought and logic than method 1 but it would fill voids like you originally requested)

Here is something to get you started:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'set range limits
endRange1 = 17
endRange2 = 5
Dim rowArray() As Variant

'step 1
For i = 3 To endRange1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
        range1EmptyRow = range1EmptyRow + 1
        ReDim Preserve rowArray(1 To UBound(rowArray) + 1) As Variant
        rowArray(UBound(rowArray)) = i
    End If
Next i

'step 2
For i = 3 To endRange2
    If Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then range2Rows = range2Rows + 1
Next i
```